# SQL Subtract Min And Max

Tags: sql, dbisam

I'm simply trying to use min() and max() functions in an expression like so:

```
SELECT WSN, MIN(TOP) - MAX(BASE) FROM PERFS GROUP BY WSN
```

But this doesn't appear to be valid SQL. I keep getting told I can't use aggregate functions in an expression. Could I get some help?

Comment: What DB? If `TOP` is reserved (e.g. mssql) `.. MIN([TOP])`

Comment: which database is this for? Something like that would work perfectly fine in MySQL.

Comment: What database platform? Works perfectly fine in DB2.

Comment: The DBMS I'm using is DBISAM from Elevate Software.

Comment: @AlexK. I'm thinking that if `TOP` was a reserved word in the poster's database, it wouldn't have let them make a table with `TOP` as a column name.

Comment: You are free to name a column as a keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I threw the question onto the DBISAM forum at Elevate (not sure why I didn't do that to begin with), and this is what they came up with:

Use two passes and create a memory table.

```
SELECT WSN, MAX(BASE) as MaxBase, MIN(TOP) as MinTop INTO memory FirstPass FROM PERFS GROUP BY WSN
;
SELECT (MaxBase - MinTop) as Calc FROM memory FirstPass
```

Thanks for all of the help guys.

Answer (score 5):

Without the database platform we can't tell that much, but try this:

```
select wsn, top - base
from
( SELECT WSN
  ,      MIN(TOP) top
  ,      MAX(BASE) base
  FROM   PERFS
  GROUP
  BY     WSN
)
```

I think the actual answer can be found in the [documentation](http://www.elevatesoft.com/manual?action=viewtopic&id=dbisam4&product=d&version=7&topic=naming_conventions) where you can find that `TOP` is a keyword indeed and tables are escaped with `"`.

Try this:

```
SELECT WSN
,      MIN("TOP") - MAX(BASE)
FROM   PERFS
GROUP
BY     WSN
```

Comment: The edited version still produces "Aggregate functions cannot be used within expressions". This is maddening. What I want to do is so simple.

Comment: @John: you mean the last example?

Comment: Yep, the last example.

Comment: And if you use `[TOP]`?

Comment: Produces the same result.

Comment: If you replace `min(top)` by `min(base)`, does it work? (I know it has an invalid end result, but just to try)

Comment: If you remove the subtraction and select just one of the two fields?

Comment: Works with just selection.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer might depend on what type of SQL you're using, as a common table expression would come in really handy for this.  I assume TOP and BASE are fields in the PERFS table?

Here's my best guess:

```
SELECT WSN, (select MIN(TOP) FROM PERFS GROUP BY WSN) - (select MAX(BASE) FROM PERFS GROUP BY WSN) FROM PERFS GROUP BY WSN
```

Edit: Patrick's answer would probably be better.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me using Oracle.  What DBMS are you using?

The statement below creates a sample inline table that you can query against. I provided example code here that can be run as-is (self contained). You have to adapt it to match your own database schema:

```
WITH TEST_DATA AS (
  SELECT 'ted' AS name, 1 as val FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'ted' AS name, 2 as val FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'ted' AS name, 3 as val FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'sam' AS name, 5 as val FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'sam' AS name, 10 as val FROM DUAL
)SELECT name, MIN(val) - MAX(val) as minmax
 FROM TEST_DATA
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: It would be more useful to OP if you use the sample in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the feeback, Patrick. I am not sure that is worth a mark down, but there you go.

Comment: I had trouble to catch the meaning of your answer, because it had all the `union`s, and I am pretty good in SQL. I think the OP doesn't understand what you are doing...

Comment: Doing that creates a sample inline table that you can query against.  I provided example code here that can be run as-is (self contained).

Comment: I know, but does OP know that?

Answer (score 0):

```
select MAX(population) - MIN(population) as value from city;
```

where the query is to find the max  - min from population in the city table

value- is the variable name where it can be changed to any